# How to Apply CSS Transition to Hover Menu

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to create a Hover menu but want to make the hovered menu opened for some time for example 2 seconds. I am trying to add CSS transition for this bu its not working. I am using the following style CSS:

```
.drop_menu {
    background:#10BDF5;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:25px;
}
.drop_menu li { float:left; }
.drop_menu li a {
    padding:3px 6px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;

    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#51C7ED;}
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:28px;
    background:#51C7ED;
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1292BB;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;

    /* LOOK AT THESE CSS TRANSITION PROPERTIES */
    -webkit-transition: visibility 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: visibility 2s ease-in;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:1px 4px;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent:11px;
    background-color:#10BDF5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#51C7ED; }
```

Please see the property just under this line: `/* LOOK AT THESE CSS TRANSITION PROPERTIES */` am I using the correct syntax or property?

Comment: I think you have to apply both of `transition` lines to `.drop_menu li ul` and remove them from `.drop_menu li:hover ul`

Comment: Please explain a bit further and add HTML here (best case: Working JSFiddle Demo).

Comment: @DominikSchmidt: Like this: http://codepen.io/jonbellah/pen/iwyFs?editors=110

Comment: @Banzay: tried but no success

Comment: here is a solution but `opacity` used instead of `visibility`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPRZKj

Comment: So, you want the menu to be opened two seconds after you left the `:hover` state? Or you want a 2 second transition? Because the first is done in the example I got from you. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @DominikSchmidt: Yes, I want to make like so the menu remains open for 2 seconds after I left the hover effect. I am using Chrome

Comment: It's like this when I visit your demo. Don't know what's the issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

This helped for me [link](http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html) where they used `opacity` instead of `display: none;`

```
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.drop_menu li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

---

Edited HTML CSS from comments:

Html Editor1: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByLVym

Html Editor2: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogzygb